# Chrome extension that replaces images with other images

Tags: javascript, json, image, replace, google-chrome-extension

how can I do a Chrome extension that replaces images with other images?

Here's my **manifest.json** code so far:

```js
{
  "name": "HaramB",
  "version": "69.0.420.666",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "This is HaramB's own extension!",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "HaramB"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "128": "images/icon.png"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/nicolas.jpg"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["onPage.js"],
    "css": ["onPage.css"]
  }]
}
```

And here's my **onPage.js** code:

```
var picture = "images/nicolas.jpg";
document.getElementsByTagName("img").setAttribute("src", picture);
```

Dont't care about the **popup.html** or the **onPage.css** files.

It's the **onPage.js** file i want  it to do it with, if it's not possible, tell me.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByTagName()` returns an Array of elements. This means you need to loop through the array and call the methods you want on them individually, like so:

```
var picture = "images/nicolas.jpg",
    images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].setAttribute("src", picture);
};
```

Note: it is preferable to use `images[i].src = ...` to using `setAttribute` as [detailed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919291/when-to-use-setattribute-vs-attribute-in-javascript)

Comment: document.images

Comment: @ppajer It kinda works, but all images are just showing as not found. Is it the **css**?

Comment: @JUSTSOMERANDOMGUY You need to get an absolute url to set as the src, otherwise it will try to look for it relative to the current url. If the image is stored inside your extension, [you have to get it via `chrome.extension.getUrl()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865789/embedding-images-into-a-chrome-extension)